# Issue in the Table with pagination component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **Table with pagination** component in my project.After importing the component,Even the default page size(i,e items per page)is 5 its showing full list(20).as shown in below image

[image]

In **TS** file inside the `ngOnInit()`

I have placed `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` has shown in below

```
ngOnInit() {
this.addsessionForm = this.fb.group({
  'startdate': [null, [Validators.required, ]],
  'lastdate': [null, [Validators.required, ]],
  'price': [this.amount, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9-!@#$%*?*]+')] ],
});
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

}

Can i  declare `this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;` inside other `ngOnInit()` whether it's a right way or not?

Comment: It's usually a lifecycle issue. Either move it to `ngAfterContentChecked` (the last hook), or use a timeout like so `setTimeout(() => this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator)`

Comment: I tried your  answers, still same the issue.

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] reproducing it. Once provided, I'll reopen your question.

Comment: OK i will do it.

Comment: https://stackblitz.io, just in case !

Comment: I solved it, thank you.@trichetriche